How to use the getIdToken method of firebase user after page reload in nextjs
I am working on a nextjs project, for user authentications I am using firebase's signInWithPhoneNumber for phone number verification, after successfull verification I get a firebase user which also has the getIdToken method to fetch a new token. My problem is after I refresh the page I cannot use this method to fetch a token as the currentUser user becomes undefined after page reload.
Mainly I want to use the getIdToken method of firebase user even after page reload. But I am in such a scenario where page reload is inevitable.
I tried storing the firebase user in localstorage but user is saved as a string and even after parsing it is an object which does not have the getIdToken method. So I cannot use it.

I posted an answer with links below. If you can't get that to work, edit your question to show what you tried.

The right way to handle page reloads is to use an auth state listener, as shown in the first code snippet in the documentation on getting the current user. You can then call getIdToken on the user to get their current ID token.

Thanks Frank van Puffelen, onAuthStateChanged worked.
